# Prestashop image not loaded properly after using cd

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-s3, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

I've recently tried to off load some of the HTTP request for images to a CDN (using S3).

my cdn is located at s3.mydomain.com

Once i've add media server everything looks okay (css, javascript). However, there is one problem. I'm getting missing picture for all of my product image.

I have tried the following:

- Turned off friendly URL --> then everything works like a charm.
  Product image can be displayed (but only when friendly URL is turned
  off.
- Regenerate thumbnails --> Still get missing image.
- Move image --> Still get missing image.

Full URL with "Friendly URL" turned on is:
http://xx.bro.do/2579-product_list_default/langdon-parka-black.jpg (does-not-work)

With "Friendly URL" turned off, it becomes:
http://xx.bro.do/img/p/2/5/7/9/2579-product_list_default.jpg

So, somehow the "Friendly URL' is not being redirected properly to the "Unfriendly URL"

Below is a snippets of my .htaccess

```
# Images
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx.bro.do$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brodo.dev$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx.bro.do$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brodo.dev$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx.bro.do$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brodo.dev$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx.bro.do$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brodo.dev$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx.bro.do$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brodo.dev$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx.bro.do$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brodo.dev$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx.bro.do$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brodo.dev$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xx.bro.do$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^brodo.dev$
RewriteRule ^([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+\.jpg$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg [L]
```

Another solution that 100% will work is by changing the actual code on the following files:

- product.tpl
- product-list.tpl
- and pretty much the rest of the files that have missing product image.

This last effort, i am trying to avoid simply because should the template change in the future then someone will have to redo the work again.

So does anyone knows how to fix this ? I appreciate any help.

Comment: did u find a solution ?? even i am facing same problem

Answer (score 2):

This method worked for me.

**Step 1**: Enable **friendly url** . check everything is working fine without media server. Make sure **friendly**  is enabled and **media server** is disabled

when step 1 is working you will see url of your products as 
**http://ec2.aws.XXXXXXXXX.com/1-large_default/faded-short-sleeves-tshirt.jpg**

**Step 2** : enable **media server** now . i,m using **cloudfront as cdn** and **s3 as bucket**

when **media server** is enabled

you will come across 2 scenarios

*1.css and js wont load and even images wont load*

*2.images will load but css and js wont load*

fix for this is: goto  **Advanced parameters** -> **Preformance** -> **CCC(combine compress and cache)**

**Smart cache for CSS** --  select **no** if it is **yes**.

**Smart cache for JavaScript** -- select **no** if it is **yes**.

After this reload your page. the site appears to be fine..

but at this stage you might come across **another 2 scenarios**

*1.css, js, images all loaded properly but product images wont load.*

*2.everything loads properly and your site is good to go. without any further changes.*

if you counter the 1st scenario follow these steps.

**step 1**. open your ftp client and navigate to your apache folder
        generally it will be residing in rootofserver/etc/apache/

```
    in my case it is rootofserver/etc/httpd
```

in your case it might be same or it might be

```
     rootofserver/etc/apahce/   
     or rootofserver/etc/apahce2/
```

**step 2**. once your inside the folder open httpd.conf file in any editor u like..

again in my case

```
        its httpd.conf  it might be same or it will be
        apaceh2.conf or apache.conf
```

**step 3**. once you have opened the file in any of the text editor
            find these below lines and **Allowoverride** set it to **All** if it is none.**(make sure 'a' is Capital)**

```
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

        #
        # Each directory to which Apache has access can be configured with respect
        # to which services and features are allowed and/or disabled in that
        # directory (and its subdirectories). 
        #
        # First, we configure the "default" to be a very restrictive set of 
        # features.  
        #
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
```

next find these set of lines and set **Allowoverride to All (make sure 'a' is Capital)**

```
        <Directory "/var/www/html">

        #
        # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
        # or any combination of:
        #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
        #
        # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
        # doesn't give it to you.
        #
        # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
        # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#options
        # for more information.
        #
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        #
        # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
        # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
        #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
        #
            AllowOverride All
```

Once you have finished editing this file.. upload it back to the server or if you can save it in the server itself do it. after uploading back to the server make sure to check this file again .if it has the edited changes. if not open **putty** or any **command line tool** your using and set

```
 chmod 0666 to the file
```

the command is

```
"sudo chmod 0666 /etc/httpd/httpd.conf"
```

copy paste and hit enter in command line interface.make sure the **file name** is as it is in your **server**. and also the **route**.

**If even after all these changes your product images are still not loading then**

Goto your **cdn console** and set the **origin as your webserver itself**. dont use s3 bucket.

ex if your **site domain name** (while development) may be

```
 ec2.userxxxxxxxx.aws.com (if amazon ec2)
```

or any other service if your     using
        provide that name as the origin for your cdn. as this will keep the files in sync between your server and the cdn where as the s3 bucket 
        you have to manually update the master copy of your site.(there are methods to achieve sync between s3 and server but i have not tried it yet)

**follow these steps and it might get your site working properly.. this worked out great for me and the site is now url friendly and media server enabled.**

Comment: this also works for me, the key point is instead of using S3 bucket you have to use the website itself as a origin. But I am still not sure how does the gzip content-encoding will work.

Comment: S3 will follow the gzip content-encoding from your origin, S3 is not able to add headers into the files.